# firing javascript function on page load

Tags: javascript, css

I have a method

toggleDrawer(this)

That expands a small window component on my webpage. It has a + icon, that, when clicked, expands the window and gets replaced with a -.

There are also a form and some filter options in this window component that when submitted, reloads the page and so when it reloads, it is shown with the window component not expanded.

How do I make it so that when I submit the form, the window is still open?

The link goes from http://link to http://link#something when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (document.location.hash === 'something') {
        someObject.toggleDrawer();
    }
};
```

Of course this will not work if you already have some events bound to the `window.onload` event. In this case you may want to use some event dispatch and add the above function to the callbacks to be invoked when the window loads. Every Javascript library has some kind of object management. For instance in jQuery you would do

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if (document.location.hash === 'something') {
        someObject.toggleDrawer();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is javascript code. Here `someObject` should be changed to whatever object the method `toggleDrawer` belongs to. You did not specify this in the question.

Comment: Or `addEventListener` resp. `attachEvent` if you want to overcome the multiple handler problem without a library.

Comment: Yes, I did not enter into the details, because then you have to take care of browser incompatibilities. I think that this is one point where using a library has some advantages.

Comment: how do I define the someObject? I am new to javascript. I am calling toggleDrawer(this) in apache velocity right now. How would I do this in js?

Comment: @SuperString: Then you should probably read a guide first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide